# Map Key Prefix to Object Label?

Tags: apex, visualforce, string, conversion

In my class I have 2 lists and I am displaying the results on a Visualforce component page.

I would like to add a column on my VF page where the value displayed is determined by the first 3 letters of the Salesforce custom object Id (String Id).

If Id startsWith 'a07' ---> replace with "Policy"  OR
If Id startsWith 'a0Y' ---> replace with "Claim"

```
public List<CoverageTeamMember> getCoverageTeam() {
    Account a = getAccount(this.controller != null ? this.controller.getId() : accountId);
        List<CoverageTeamMember> l = getCoverageTeam(a);

    return l;
    }

    //Account query to get Servicer 1 & 2
    private Account getAccount( ID account ) {
        return [ SELECT Id, Producer__r.Name, Producer__r.Email__c, Producer__r.Work_Phone__c, Servicer_1__c, Serv1__r.Name, Serv1__r.Email__c, Serv1__r.Work_Phone__c, Servicer_2__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :account ];
    }

    //Policy query to get Active Policy Coverage Team Members
    private List<CoverageTeamMember> getCoverageTeam( Account account ) {
        List<CoverageTeamMember> result = this.getStaticCoverageTeam( account );

        for ( AggregateResult records : [ 
            SELECT Id, Servicer_Department_Name__c role, Servicer__r.Id name, Servicer__r.Name actualname, Servicer__r.Email__c email, Servicer__r.Work_Phone__c phone, Active__c a
            FROM Policy__c
            WHERE Account__c = :account.Id AND 
                Servicer_Department_Name__c != null AND
                Servicer__c != null AND
                Active__c = True
            GROUP BY Id, Servicer_Department_Name__c, Servicer__r.Id, Servicer__r.Name, Servicer__r.Email__c, Servicer__r.Work_Phone__c, Active__c
        ] ) {
            result.add( new CoverageTeamMember( records ) );
        }

    //Claims query to get Active Claims & Policy Coverage Team Members
        for ( AggregateResult claims : [ 
            SELECT Id, Servicer_Department_Name__c role, Servicer__r.Id name, Servicer__r.Name actualname, Servicer__r.Email__c email, Servicer__r.Work_Phone__c phone, IsClosed__c a
            FROM Claim__c 
            WHERE Account__c = :account.Id AND 
                Servicer_Department_Name__c != null AND
                Servicer__c != null AND
                IsClosed__c = False
            GROUP BY Id, Servicer_Department_Name__c, Servicer__r.Id, Servicer__r.Name, Servicer__r.Email__c, Servicer__r.Work_Phone__c, IsClosed__c
        ] ) {
            result.add( new CoverageTeamMember( claims ) );
        }

        return result;
    }

    private List<CoverageTeamMember> getStaticCoverageTeam( Account account ) {
        List<CoverageTeamMember> result = new List<CoverageTeamMember>();
        result.add( new CoverageTeamMember('Client Account', 'Producer', account.Producer__r.Id, account.Producer__r.Name, account.Producer__r.Email__c, account.Producer__r.Work_Phone__c) );
        result.add( new CoverageTeamMember('Client Account', 'Client Owner', account.Serv1__r.Id, account.Serv1__r.Name, account.Serv1__r.Email__c,account.Serv1__r.Work_Phone__c ) );
        //result.add( new CoverageTeamMember( 'P&C Servicer Coordinator', account.Servicer_1__c ) );
        //result.add( new CoverageTeamMember( 'Benefits Coordinator', account.Servicer_2__c ) );   
        return result;
    }

    public class CoverageTeamMember {
    public final String id { get; set; }
    public final String role { get; set; }
    public final String name { get; set; }
    public final String actualname { get; set; }
    public final String email { get; set; }
    public final String phone { get; set; } 


    public CoverageTeamMember( AggregateResult records) {
        this(     
        String.valueOf( records.get( 'id' ) ), 
        String.valueOf( records.get( 'role' ) ), 
        String.valueOf( records.get( 'name' ) ), 
        String.valueOf( records.get( 'actualname' ) ),
        String.valueOf( records.get( 'email' ) ), 
        String.valueOf( records.get( 'phone') ) );
    }

    public CoverageTeamMember(String id, String role, String name, String actualname, String email, String phone) {
        this.id = id;
        this.role = role;
        this.name = name;
        this.actualname = actualname;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `a07` and `a0Y` are `keyPrefix` values for `Policy__c` and `Claim__c`, respectively. Normally you can convert an `Id` to the label of its' `SObjectType` as follows:

```
public static String getSObjectTypeLabel(Id input)
{
    return input.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getLabel();
}
```

However, you have a couple things in your structure complicating that level of simplicity:

1. Your property is of the `String` type, meaning you have to convert it to an `Id` first
2. Your property is *named* `Id`, so you cannot call `Id.valueOf`.

You can add the following property to your `CoverageTeamMember` wrapper. If you change the type of your `id` property to `Id`, you can remove the need to cast altogether:

```
public class CoverageTeamMember
{
    public String id { get; set; }
    // replace with public Id id { get; set; }
    // other properties

    public String sObjectLabel
    {
        get
        {
            SObjectType idType = ((Id)this.id).getSObjectType();
            return idType.getDescribe().getLabel();
        }
        // no setter required
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian!  Receiving this error > "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [String].valueOf(String)"  - What am I missing here?

Comment: public class CoverageTeamMember {
    
    public final String id { get; set; }
       
        // other properties
    public String sObjectType
    {
        get
        {
            SObjectType idType = id.valueOf(this.id).getSObjectType();
            return idType.getDescribe().getLabel();
        }
        // no setter required
    }
    public final String role { get; set; }
    public final String name { get; set; }
    public final String actualname { get; set; }
    public final String email { get; set; }
    public final String phone { get; set; }

Comment: @SFDCCrystalCo Answer updated.

Comment: @Adran Larson: my VF component is still showing the 'ID' of the record rather than the sObjectLabel.  Would you have any ideas why?

Comment: <apex:column>
 <apex:facet name="header">Coverage Team Level</apex:facet>
 {! member.id }
 </apex:column>

Comment: You need to reference the new property: `{member.sObjectLabel}`. @SFDC

Comment: That was it!!  Thanks @Adrian Larson!!  Where should I send the beers?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the object name as set in SF, then you could use the built in key prefix functionality as described [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-to-find-Object-Type-from-Record-ID-Prefix&language=en_US):

> ```
> public class SchemaGlobalDescribe{
>     public static String findObjectNameFromRecordIdPrefix(String recordIdOrPrefix){
>         String objectName = '';
>         try{
>             //Get prefix from record ID
>             //This assumes that you have passed at least 3 characters
>             String myIdPrefix = String.valueOf(recordIdOrPrefix).substring(0,3);
>
>             //Get schema information
>             Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd =  Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
>
>             //Loop through all the sObject types returned by Schema
>             for(Schema.SObjectType stype : gd.values()){
>                 Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = stype.getDescribe();
>                 String prefix = r.getKeyPrefix();
>                 System.debug('Prefix is ' + prefix);
>
>                 //Check if the prefix matches with requested prefix
>                 if(prefix!=null && prefix.equals(myIdPrefix)){
>                     objectName = r.getName();
>                     System.debug('Object Name! ' + objectName);
>                     break;
>                 }
>             }
>         }catch(Exception e){
>             System.debug(e);
>         }
>         return objectName;
>     }
> }
> ```

Then you can pass in prefix and get back object name:

> String objectName =
>   SchemaGlobalDescribe.findObjectNameFromRecordIdPrefix('500');
>       System.debug(objectName);